# Select statement connecting from two databases (in the same server)

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to connect two databases with the same MySQL query, but i have failed to do so. Here is my logical procedure:

```
<?php
 // First connection
 $connection1 = mysqli_connect($dbhost1, $dbuser1, $dbpass1, $dbname1);
 // Second Connection
 $connection2 = mysqli_connect($dbhost2, $dbuser2, $dbpass2, $dbname2);

 $query = "SELECT DATABASE1 . TABLE1 . 'variable'
           FROM DATABASE1 . TABLE1 
           WHERE (DATABASE1 . TABLE1 . 'variable')
           IN (WHERE DATABASE2 . TABLE2 . 'variable'
               FROM DATABASE2 . TABLE2)";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection2, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "$row['variable']";
 }

?>
```

When I run the MySQL query in the SQL run module, i get the expected result, but when i try to run it in php it does not work.
Here is the actual code:

```
<?php
// First connection this connects to the FIU database
 $connection1 = mysqli_connect($dbhost1, $dbuser1, $dbpass1, $dbname1);
 // Second Connection this connects to the FAU database
 $connectionINT = mysqli_connect($dbhost2, $dbuser2, $dbpass2, $dbname2);

 $queryCheaters = " SELECT FAU. FAU_01212015 . `stdName` FROM FAU . FAU_01212015 
 WHERE (FAU. FAU_01212015 . `remoteIP`) 
 IN (SELECT FIU . FIU_01232015 . `remoteIP` FROM FIU. FIU_01232015)";

 $check = mysqli_query($connectionINT, $queryCheaters);
?>
```

I have run both select statements individually and i get variables back on the while loop, but i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Thanks ahead of time =)

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: the subselect is rather pointless. why not just use a standard left-join? Plus, you have absolutely NO error handling, and are simply assuming your db operations are succeeding. Try `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($connectionINT));` and see what's blowing up.

Comment: I just try using try or die error handling, but the webpage is still up and running and no error message shows up. Here is the error handling code: if(!mysqli_query($connectionINT, $queryCheaters)){
  die("Database query not working:" .
   mysqli_error($connectionINT) );
 }

Comment: And you don't need two separate connections to do that (the second connection isn't used anyway; or in this particular case the first connection)